# Mysql loop trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to do Closure tables with parentId so I have two tables (Subjects and SubjectsTree). When I insert a record in Subjects I need to add records in SubjectsTree for every Subjects.Id = new.ParentId. I'm trying in that way:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER test AFTER INSERT ON Subjects
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE ids INT;
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM Subjects inner join SubjectsTree on SubjectsTree.DescendantId = new.ParentId;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;
        ins_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur INTO ids;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE ins_loop;
            END IF;
            INSERT INTO SubjectsTree VALUES (ids, new.Id);
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur;
    insert into SubjectsTree values (new.Id, new.Id);
END; //
```

But it doesn't work just because it repeats for all records in Subjects! And when I try without loop it doesn't.

Why does this code aren't executed for each record in Subjects?

create trigger test after insert on Subjects
for each row
    insert into some_test_table values ('test value');

And how can I solve this problem? Or maybe there is a better way?

```
Subjects table: 
   Id int PRI
   Name longtext
   ParentId int

SubjectsTree table:
   AncestorId int PRI
   DescendantId int PRI
```

Comment: "Why does this code aren't executed for each record in Subjects?" You might need to do a LEFT JOIN on your CURSOR instead and maybe add a where`SELECT Id FROM Subjects LEFT join SubjectsTree on SubjectsTree.DescendantId = new.ParentId; [where...?]`

Comment: I probably explained not clearly. When I create a trigger with loop it doesn't work correctly because my loop repeats for all needed records and then "FOR EACH ROW" repeats for all records (as I understood). But without loop for each row doesn't repeat as well. I checked my query with inner join and it returns correct result.

Comment: @Raymond you were absolutely right! There is a problem in my join. With more records I saw that. But I don't understand why it isn't right. For example: SELECT Id FROM Subjects inner join SubjectsTree on SubjectsTree.DescendantId = new.ParentId; it's supposed to be the right query, isn't it? Left join doesn't suit because it returns all records from the left table. And where doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0):

Have solved this problem much easier.

```
drop trigger if exists test;
create trigger test after insert on Subjects
for each row
    insert into SubjectsTree select AncestorId, new.Id, 1 from SubjectsTree 
    where DescendantId = new.ParentId union all select new.Id, new.Id, 1;
```